# Cannot understand this output from getw

Tags: c

I have this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int a = getw(stdin);

    if(ferror(stdin)) {
        printf("error occurred\n");
        exit(1);
    }        
    printf("%u\n", a);

}
```

And I getting:

```
$ ./readstdin 
9876
909588537
```

Can you help explain the output please?

My machine:
Linux abc-ubuntu 3.2.0-65-generic #98-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 11 20:27:07 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Where is `getw` defined?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, using `%u` to print an `int` is undefined behavior. Either use `%d` or cast `a` to `unsigned` in your `printf` call.

Second, [`getw()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/getw.html) reads in a word (or `sizeof(int)` bytes) from the stream. It performs binary I/O, not formatted I/O.

Assuming ASCII, the characters `9` `8` `7` `6` maps to values `0x39`, `0x38`, `0x37` and `0x36` respectively. In your system `sizeof(int) == 4`, so `getw` reads in those four bytes, stores them into the space of an `int`, and returns that value. In a little-endian system, the least significant byte is stored at the lowest address, so the stored value is `0x36373839`, or `909588537` in decimal.

Answer (score 2):

If you print the bytes of the value returned from `getw`, you'll get some insight.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void printBytes(int a)
{
   int a1 = (a & 0xFF000000) >> 24;
   int a2 = (a & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
   int a3 = (a & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
   int a4 = (a & 0x000000FF);
   printf("%c%c%c%c\n", a1, a2, a3, a4);
}

int main() {

    int a = getw(stdin);

    if(ferror(stdin)) {
        printf("error occurred\n");
        return 1;
    }        
    printBytes(a);
    printf("%u\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample input:

```
1234
```

Output:

```
4321
875770417
```

On my system, which is little endian, the stream "1234" is converted to `(4 << 24) + (3 << 16) + ( 2 << 8) + 1)` by `getw`. On  a big endian system, the same stream would be converted to `(1 << 24) + (2 << 16) + (3 << 8) + 4`, which will result in `825373492`.

Comment: Why is the output reversed? Your machine is little endian?

Comment: @FiddlingBits, yes, my system is a little endian system.

Comment: Might be worth noting in your answer.

Comment: @RSahu How does endianess impact the answer here? I think the first byte is stored as the least significant byte and then following bytes are stored in the order of increased significance. T.C. has a good explanation above.

Comment: @RSahu Endianness will only impact how the bytes are arranged (addressed) in memory. Why should it affect the final answer (value of the data stored).

Comment: @abc, the values of the bytes representing an `int` are interpreted differently in big endian and little endian systems. If the bytes of an `int` are `b1`, `b2`, `b3`, and `b4`, that number is `(b1 << 24) + (b2 << 16) + (b3 << 8) + b4` in a big endian system and `(b4 << 24) + (b3 << 16) + (b2 << 8) + b1` in a little endian system.

Comment: @abc Endianness affects the answer because the actual bytes read are reversed by the implementation on a little endian machine. That is, the implementation of `getw` on a little endian machine changes `'9' '8' '7' '6'` to `'6' '7' '8' '9'`. On a big endian machine, no byte swapping is necessary, so `'9' '8' '7' '6'` would still be `'9' '8' '7' '6'`. The manual for `getw` references `fread`; try `fread(&a, sizeof a, 1, stdin);` to see what I mean.